# How to send a database to SkyDrive?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I have a database, access it with LINQ to SQL and storing some texts in it.

I want to do a backup of it into SkyDrive. It is a mobile app, and should not get too big. so I thought of converting it to xml and saving it to a text file in SkyDrive.

This doesn't look good, also I found I will struggle with some errors like circular references,etc.

what is the best approach for this purpose? thanks.

Comment: If it was SQLite database, then you could just upload a whole database file...

Answer (score 0):

Might want to start with a blog post I wrote - Adding SkyDrive support to your Windows Phone application. You will need to download the Live SDK (unless you want to use the REST API manually, which I can see no reason for at this point).

Uploading is fairly simple after that, given that you obtained the proper session init:

```
 client = new LiveConnectClient(App.MicrosoftAccountSession);
 client.UploadCompleted += MicrosoftAccountClient_UploadCompleted;
 client.UploadProgressChanged += MicrosoftAccountClient_UploadProgressChanged;
 client.UploadAsync("me/skydrive", Binder.Instance.CurrentlyUploading,
 stream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
```

Comment: thanks @Swapil. but I already can send data to SkyDrive. but my problem is how to upload the database, i.e. table by table, as an xml, etc.